# Service to Allow for IP Discover Across Subnets

Tags: ip, usb, subnet, service-discovery

I am working on an embedded software product that runs on an Ubuntu edge computer with multiple network ports.

The software allows the user to change the IP address of the ports via a locally hosted web interface.

In the scenario that a customer changed an IP on one of our devices, but then forgets their setting I am looking for an easy strategy to walk them through detecting the IP.

Ideally this tool would be usable by non-sophisticated customers (we don’t want to walk them through using Wireshark or command line tools).

Is there a service we can setup on our machine that will broadcast its identity across subnets using another protocol like UDP or EtherNet/IP? Then a simple tool the client could install on their computer to ‘scan’ for our devices?

The edge computers also have USB ports if it is easier to broadcast an identify there.

Answer (score 0):

Changing a local IP address to something invalid (=not compatible with its local subnet) generally disables all L3 communication. Limited broadcasts (to 255.255.255.255) still work, but answering to them by unicast most likely won't. The same goes for multicasting - but you could use that for discovery both ways.

Also, the common link-level discovery protocols (like LLDP or CDP) still work since they don't rely on IP.

However, all that is limited to the connected L2 segment at most. Discovery *across* subnets isn't possible without some kind of infrastructure (discovery sensors, central server, multicast routing, ...). A reasonable way would be dynamic DNS but then again, that requires IP to work.

I think you'd need to take a step back and reevaluate your design. One way would be to verify a user's reconfiguration before it becomes permanent. For instance, you could have a user change the IP setup and then forward the session to the new IP address. If the session isn't continued within five minutes or so on the new address, it reverses to the previous config.

Additionally, some kind of out-of-band management could be useful.